# EclipseLink cache size default... is that Per Entity or Total?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, jpa, eclipselink

Eclipselink offers this config parameter: `eclipselink.cache.size.default`.

It also offers an entity cache size: `eclipselink.cache.size.Employee` (if you had an entity called `Employee`.

So If I set: `eclipselink.cache.size.default=500`, does that mean 500 total slots for all entities? Or 500 slots per each type of Entity?

Thanks!

Comment: Each entity has its own cache, and will use the default size of 500.

Comment: can you put your comment as an answer so I may give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each entity has its own cache, and will use the default size of 500.  Inheritance is one case where this isn't true - subclasses do not have their own cache and instead use root entity's cache.  So if you had Employee extend a Person entity, there would be a cache of up to 500 Person instances, which would include Employee and any other subclass instances as well.

Comment: Is the inheritance exception you mention above true for both @mappedsuperclass and @inheritance?

Comment: is there a way to set default expiry time for all entities?